# How to retrieve function test result in pytest to write out to my own log files

Tags: python, pytest

I've been researching/learning this for a couple of days now but can't seem to figure this out.  All I'm looking to do is retrieve the status of each test function so I can write out my own log files.

I'm pretty sure the parts I need are the TestReport object, hooks pytest_testreport_status and pytest_runtest_makereport.  I'm fairly new to pytest and I'm just not getting how to "glue" this all together to make this work.

Here is a simple test.  The last statement in the test is a function call (process_test_function_results) which processes the test results and writes results out to log file.  I believe what I want is to pass the TestReport object to process_test_function_results(). Just not sure how to make this work with the hooks and put this all together.

```
import pytest
import lib.dnet_generic as mynet_generic
import datetime

@pytest.mark.parametrize("cmd",[
    "show system version | no-more",
    "show bgp summary | no-more",
    "show bgp neighbor | no-more",
    ])
def test_cmds(logger, device_connections, testinfo, error_queue, cmd, rp_logger):

    dut =       testinfo['topo_map']['devices']['dev3']['name'] 
    connection = device_connections[dut]
    cmdOutput = connection.send_command(cmd)

    if "ERROR" in cmdOutput:
        err_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        err_mess = (f"ERROR: The command <{cmd}> returned an error.\n"
                    f"Time: {err_time}\n"
                    f"Device: {dut}\n"
                   )
        mess_level = "error"
        message = {'level' : mess_level , 'message' : err_mess} 
        error_queue.put(message)
        connection._write_session_log(err_mess)

    mynet_generic.process_test_function_results(error_queue, logger,testinfo,rp_logger)
```

Here is a snippet of what the custom output log file looks like that is written to via the process_test_function_results method. You'll notice the Result: is empty.  I believe what I want is to fill in Result: with TestReport.outcome

```
------------------------------------------------------------
---- Begin Function Test: test_isis_cmds[show
---- Start Time: Thu Oct 03 16:39:15  2019
------------------------------------------------------------


    --------------------------------------
    ---- Test Function completed at: Thu Oct 03 16:39:16  2019
    ---- Result:
    --------------------------------------

------------------------------------------------------------
---- Begin Function Test: test_isis_cmds[show
---- Start Time: Thu Oct 03 16:39:16  2019
------------------------------------------------------------


    --------------------------------------
    ---- Test Function completed at: Thu Oct 03 16:39:16  2019
    ---- Result:
    --------------------------------------

------------------------------------------------------------
---- Begin Function Test: test_isis_cmds[show
---- Start Time: Thu Oct 03 16:39:16  2019
------------------------------------------------------------


    --------------------------------------
    ---- Test Function completed at: Thu Oct 03 16:39:17  2019
    ---- Result:
    --------------------------------------
```

Thanks for any help.
Al

Answer (score 1):

you can define the hooks in conftest.py which has to reside in the PWD or system path

PFA the sample test code to check if the input number is positive

test.py

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("number",[1,3,0,-1])
def test_hooks(number):
    assert int(number) >= 0
```

conftest.py --> has the hook logic to capture results to log

```
import pytest

@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    log_file = "test.log"
    outcome = yield
    result = outcome.get_result()
    if result.when == "call":
        try:
            with open(log_file, "a") as f:
                f.write(result.nodeid + "   " + result.outcome+ "    " + str(result.duration)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error", e)
            pass
```

the variable outcome in the snippet is TestReport object which contains run details

Sample Logfile output

```
test.py::test_hooks[1]   passed    0.000999927520752
test.py::test_hooks[3]   passed    0.000999927520752
test.py::test_hooks[0]   passed    0.00100016593933
test.py::test_hooks[-1]   failed    0.00100016593933
```

you can modify the hook logic based on your requirement. This can be a handy link https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html for object references in pytest